# Bought 2nd hand AppleTV, Privacy?

Tags: appletv

I bought a second hand appletv. My main concern now is my privacy.

Will the person from who I bought it from see what I am doing with it? Will he see when I try to log in using my appleId and see where I live and what I buy?

Comment: I think you are being paranoid... However, if you are truly concerned, find online instructions on how to wipe and restore the Apple TV. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joS58kEIdPw

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it is very unlikely, but if you want to you can do a factory reset which will wipe the device settings, and also download and install the latest system software for your device.

[Apple TV (2nd and 3rd generation): Restoring your Apple TV](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4367)